# What logics do the transfinite length pebble games capture?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

See e.g. [Libkin, *Elements of finite model theory*](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf) for background on the usual pebble game. Below, all languages are finite and relational, and "$\uparrow$" denotes an expression being undefined.

---

Suppose $\mathfrak{C}=(C;...)$ is a structure in a language $\Sigma$. Given maps $$f_1: X_1\rightarrow C,...,f_n:X_n\rightarrow C$$ with each $X_i$ a (not necessarily downwards-closed) set of ordinals and a quantifier-free $\Sigma$-formula $\varphi$, write $$\mathfrak{C}\models_v\varphi(f_1,...,f_n)$$ iff there are ordinals $\alpha_1<\sup(X_1),...,\alpha_n<\sup(X_n)$ such that for all $\beta_1\in X_1\setminus\alpha_1,...,\beta_n\in X_n\setminus\alpha_n$ we have $\mathfrak{C}\models\varphi(f_1(\beta_1),...,f_n(\beta_n))$ in the usual sense.

*Intuitively, this will give us a way of talking about eventual behavior of a moving pebble. Note that disjunction plays weirdly here: we can have $\mathfrak{C}\models_v\varphi\vee\psi$ even if $\mathfrak{C}\not\models_v\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{C}\not\models_v\psi$. Similarly, we lose bivalence.*

We can use $\models_v$ to make sense of transfinitely long pebble games as follows. Fix two structures $\mathfrak{A}=(A;...),\mathfrak{B}=(B;...)$ in the same language $\Sigma$, an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (= number of pebbles, which for simplicity I'll index from $1$), and an $\theta\in\mathsf{Ord}$ (= number of moves). The game $\mathsf{Peb}_\theta^n(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ is played as follows:

- At the start of each stage $\alpha<\theta$ of the game we will have for each $1\le i\le n$ maps $$p_i^\alpha: X_i^\alpha\rightarrow A\quad\mbox{and}\quad q_i^\alpha: Y_i^\alpha\rightarrow B$$ with each $X_i^\alpha,Y_i^\alpha\subseteq\alpha$.
- As usual, $\mathsf{Duplicator}$ wins iff for each $\alpha<\theta$ and each quantifier-free $\Sigma$-formula $\varphi$ we have $$\mathfrak{A}\models_v\varphi(p_1^\alpha,...,p_n^\alpha)\quad\iff\quad \mathfrak{B}\models_v\varphi(q_1^\alpha,...,q_n^\alpha).$$
- During stage $\alpha$, $\mathsf{Spoiler}$ chooses to move on either the "$\mathfrak{A}$-side" or "$\mathfrak{B}$-side." Assuming the former WLOG, they then choose an $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ and an $a\in A$, and we then set $$p_j^{\alpha+1}(\alpha)=\begin{cases}
  a & \mbox{ if }j=i,\\
  p_j^\alpha(\max(dom(p_j^\alpha))) & \mbox{ if that maximum exists},\\
  \uparrow & \mbox{ otherwise}.
  \end{cases}$$ $\mathsf{Duplicator}$ would then respond by picking a $b\in B$, and we would then set $$q_j^{\alpha+1}(\alpha)=\begin{cases}
  b & \mbox{ if }j=i,\\
  q_j^\alpha(\max(dom(q_j^\alpha))) & \mbox{ if that maximum exists},\\
  \uparrow & \mbox{ otherwise}.
  \end{cases}$$

Write $\mathfrak{A}\simeq^n_\theta\mathfrak{B}$ iff $\mathsf{Duplicator}$ has a winning strategy in $\mathsf{Peb}^n_\theta(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ (of course $\mathfrak{A}\not\simeq^n_\theta\mathfrak{B}$ does not obviously imply that $\mathsf{Spoiler}$ has a winning strategy, since these games are "long"). For example, let $\mathfrak{R}$ be the usual linear order of real numbers, and $\mathfrak{L}$ the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) as a linear order. Then $\mathfrak{R}\not\simeq^2_{\omega+1}\mathfrak{L}$: $\mathsf{Spoiler}$ can spend $\omega$-many moves marching the $p$-pebbles cofinally up $\mathfrak{R}$, and then at stage $\omega+1$ can move $q_1$ to something bigger than anything yet achieved by $q_2$. Of course classically we have $\mathfrak{R}\equiv_{\infty,\omega}\mathfrak{L}$ so this is a genuine difference from the usual finite-length pebble games.

I'm generally interested in any information about these transfinite pebble games (e.g. have they been looked at before?), but most especially:

> What logic does $\simeq^n_\theta$ correspond to for $\theta>\omega$?

I suspect this might be overly-ambitious, so I'd be happy with partial answers, e.g. for $n=2$ and $\theta=$ some specific limit ordinal $>\omega$, or a characterization of the $\simeq^n_\theta$s on the ordinals, or etc.

Comment: What is the logical characterization of the normal transfinite back-and-forth game? And do you have an example showing that this isn't just the $n$-variable fragment of whatever logic that is?

Comment: @JamesHanson I don't actually think it has a too-snappy one - e.g. a game characterization for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ is [much more complicated](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0108).

Comment: @JamesHanson Belatedly, here's a negative observation: Duplicator-winnability of EF-games of arbitrary ordinal length correspond to $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$-equivalence (= isomorphism), but I don't see how to construe "$2$-variable $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$-equivalence" as anything stronger than $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$, which is a problem since $\mathfrak{R}\cong_p\mathfrak{L}$.